# Rails and Rpsec - Creating a test-only class that inherits from an application class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having a problem attempting to create a class just for testing in my spec suite.

I have an ActiveRecord Model, `Change`, which belongs to a `ChangeType`. `ChangeType` itself is inherited by each specific change type (e.g. `ChangeOfDetails`).

To test some of the functionality of `ChangeType`, I'm creating a new class in my spec suite:

```
class ChangeTypeExtender < ChangeType
  ...
end
```

If I use an extending class defined in app, it works correctly:

```
let(:change_type) { ChangeOfDetails.first_or_create }
let(:change)      { build :change, change_type: change_type }
```

If the bogus class is defined inside the spec file it is to be used in, it works correctly:

```
class ChangeTypeExtender < ChangeType
  ...
end

let(:change_type) { ChangeTypeExtender.first_or_create }
let(:change)      { build :change, change_type: change_type }
```

However, if the `ChangeTypeExtender` is defined in its own file (in this case, `spec/support/change_type_extender.rb`), and required in `spec_helper`:

```
let(:change_type) { ChangeTypeExtender.first_or_create }
let(:change)      { build :change, change_type: change_type }
#=> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Exception: ChangeType(#111347560) expected, got ChangeTypeExtender(#116569860)
```

What's even stranger, the test class is definitely inheriting methods correctly from `ChangeType`

```
change_type = ChangeTypeExtender.first_or_create
change_type.method(:method_on_change_type).source_location #=> ["/.../app/models/change_type.rb", 36]
```

It should be noted that while I am using FactoryGirl, I don't think it's an FG issue, as the following also has issues:

```
change = Change.new
change.change_type = ChangeTypeExtender.first_or_create
#=> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Exception: ChangeType(#111347560) expected, got ChangeTypeExtender(#116569860)
```

Finally, I definitely have `config.cache_classes = false` in my `config/environments/test.rb`.

Any direction as to why this would be occurring would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Some more info, it looks like some classes are being defined multiple times.

```ruby
ChangeType.object_id #=> 101360070
VariationSupport::ChangeTypeExtender.superclass #=> ChangeType(...)
VariationSupport::ChangeTypeExtender.superclass.object_id #=> 106320540
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm still not sure why I was encountering classes defined multiple times, but I've come up with an acceptable workaround for the issue.

The class can be defined in a shared context using rspec

`shared_context :change_type_extender_class do
  class ChangeTypeExtender < ChangeType
    ...
  end
end`

Then included in the spec of your choice by including the shared context (`include_context :change_type_extender_class`).

I'm still curious as to why I'm seeing this odd behavior, and would be grateful if somebody could explain it to me.